# Intellij IDEA - display 2 spaces indent as 4 spaces

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation

At work our project is indented with 2 spaces. Somehow they don't want to use tabs for indenting.
I personally can't read code indented with 2 spaces very well and would prefer 4 spaces.

Is there anything I can do without changing the code, to improve the readability for me?

Thanks four your answers!

Answer (score 1):

No.

A tab is something that can be openly and freely defined to be as many spaces as you want it to be, such that one tab could equal 3 spaces if you really wanted to (although I think both factions would be justified in their outrage over such an abomination).

A *space* is a hard-coded, explicitly defined value, and if two *spaces* are used, then it can only ever be two *spaces*.

Your only hope is to advocate - strongly advocate - for better code standards.  You'll have to either extol the benefits of tabs since they can be used for variable space, or you'll have to demonstrate why having four spaces is preferable to two for readability's sake.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried to talk to the decision makers, but they are like "we already had that in the old project, so we will do it the same way in the new project".